# ASP.NET Model Binder Infinite Loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm having an issue with the default ASP.NET url-form-encoded model binder where it enters an infinite loop.

The issue can be reproduced by creating an ApiController:

```
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Put([FromBody] Data data)
    {
        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
    }
}
```

And the following data models:

```
public class Data
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public SubData SubData { get; set; }
}

public class SubData 
{
    public IList<Item> Items { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public IList<SubItem> SubItems { get; set; }
}

public class SubItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then call the controller via:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/api/Test',
    type: 'PUT',
    data: {
        Title: 'hello',
        SubData: {
            Items: null
        }
     }
});
```

I've created an issue and full example here:  https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/2280

**The Problem**

Passing the Data.SubData.Items property as *null* causes the model binder to go into an infinite loop.  This will continue to consume memory until there isn't any left.  Once all the memory is gone, the TestController is called and the data parameter is null (no exception is thrown).  Passing an empty array or not passing that property at all will allow the binder to work properly.

Debugging the asp.net source indicates that the infinite loop is located in the CollectionModelBinder.BindComplexCollectionFromIndexes method.  The indexNames iterator is a while(true) and binding the sub item always works, didBind is never set to false, so it never breaks out of foreach.  It selects this method because the value from the client is null.

Simply sending an empty array is not sufficient since an attacker could easily use this to launch of DOS attack.

**Questions**

1. Where can I report this or get further help?  The codeplex site looks dead and this is for MVC 4.
2. Is there a way to override the behavior of the model binder to avoid this situation (I'm looking for a global solution)?

Any help would be appreciated.